# If KVM is working, why does VMX show as disabled?

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, intel-vt-x

I have VT-x enabled in the BIOS. I'm running qemu/kvm/Manjaro. `lscpu` says

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Flags: ... vmx ... 
Virtualization features:
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
```

In addition,

```
$ sudo rdmsr -f 2:0 0x3A
5
```

which means that

- The VMX configuration is locked
- VMX is disabled in the SMX (“Safer Mode Extensions”) state
- VMX is enabled outside of the SMX state

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/422641/65320) gives me hope: if `kvm` loads, then VMX is working. Indeed, `qemu` with `kvm` as its accelerator works just fine (or at least seems to). So then why does it show VMX as being disabled for the purposes of the multihit vulnerability?

An example `qemu` run:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic -vga none -net none -nodefaults -machine q35 -accel kvm -cpu host -smp sockets=1,dies=1,cores=2,threads=2 -m 512M ...

QEMU 6.0.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) info kvm
info kvm
kvm support: enabled
```

The guest (pfSense, in this case) is running fine so far.

Comment: My initial response would be that there is a difference between VT-d and VT-x but from what you found and from what I gathered that might not be the case. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/multihit.html

But I would still say that KVM works with VT-d, VT-x is not required. but double check dmesg?

Comment: @NiKiZe VT-d and VT-x are certainly different; but here I've attempted to focus on VT-x. Where does VT-d come into play?

Comment: You'll almost certainly need to direct this question to the developers.

Comment: Indeed so it seems. will delete incorrect information.
what does dmesg say, and what does trying to run a KVM enabled machine give you ex: `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -M q35 -m 1024 -cpu host` ?

Comment: @NiKiZe I've edited to show some information on an example qemu run. What specifically are you looking for in dmesg; and are you interested in the host or the guest?

Comment: simplified: VT-x is support for a second layer of page tables in the MMU attached to the CPU, and VT-d is support for page tables in the MMU attached to the PCIe root complex. You need the latter for transparently passing down devices to VMs, as they program guest physical addresses into DMA capable devices, and these need to be translated during DMA operations.

Comment: I just wanted to say I'm seeing the same thing happen with a Skylake CPU and Fedora Linux. All hardware virtualization enabled in BIOS, yet `lscpu` claims "Vulnerability Itlb multihit: KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled". Very confusing. I wonder if it's a kernel bug?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for a question... It was interesting for me too...
So, after reading this, and https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/multihit.html
it's become clear: vmx looks present and not disabled by bios. Vulnerability present, but now vmx is not in use, thus is just disabled. when some kvm is run and use vmx, situations changed:

```
 $ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/itlb_multihit 
 KVM: Mitigation: Split huge pages
```

meaning, that vulnerability present, but mitigated by kvm by splitting pages.

Answer (score 0):

In short, even though the multihit vulnerability mitigation may temporarily disable VMX, your system's VT-x is still enabled and working fine. The successful operation of KVM and your virtual machine indicates that VT-x is being utilized for hardware acceleration as expected. So, there is no need to be concerned about the reported VMX disablement for the multihit vulnerability.